# Recursive Flex View Component

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I have a Flex component that is a view of a data Object that recursively has a reference to itself.

For example if you had an Employee class that references a boss field of type Person, I'd like to nest the same view for that Boss. This shouldn't be an infinite recursive relationship (e.g. I'd only be viewing the boss field of each object).

I've tried creating an MXML component that references itself but when I run it locks up (seems like it gets into a recursive loop).

Is there anything you can do like includeInLayout conditions that will make sure it doesn't even instantiate that component.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to have two states, like "normal" and "boss" and set includeIn="normal" for your nested component. By default the itemCreationPolicy will be set to "deferred" but you can define it anyways to be sure. You can finally set the currentState property to "boss" directly in the MXML declaration.

That way the nested component will only be created when current component state is normal.

Note that if you already have some states you'll have to duplicate those states and add "AndBoss" suffix to the duplicate and create 2 state groups, "normalGroup", and "bossGroup" and assign includeIn="normalGroup" to your component.

```
<!--MyComponent-->
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" >
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal"/>
        <s:State name="boss"/>
    </s:states>
    <component:MyComponent includeIn="normal" 
                           currentState="boss" 
                           itemCreationPolicy="diferred"/>
</s:Group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting some code would be helpful. Off the top of my head I'd just have a property that default's to false called "isChild." The component, onCreationComplete adds itself to itself only if isChild=false. It makes sure to set isChild = true when adding it. Now when the creationComplete happens on the child, it won't create another level.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that MXML components don't like to take their own Class as a child, but my experience is that AS doesn't have that limitation.